# Laravel no encuentra el controlador en App\Http\Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy creando un proyecto en laravel, he creado un controlador, y cuando intento vincularlo a la ruta, me lanza un error que no lo encuentra.
les muestro el codigo 
   CONTROLADOR: Home

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Home;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Home extends Controller
{
 public function base();       //controlador home
  {
   return view('index');
   }
 }
```

WEB APP

```
Route::get('/','Home.php@base');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los controladores en Laravel se invocan y se crean del modo siguiente:

```
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@index');
```

> Como puedes notar el controlador debe tener la sintáxis de la primer
>   palabra en singular seguido inmediatamente de la palabra controller,
>   checa que cada palabra inicia con mayúscula; así mismo te digo que no
>   requiere la exstensión php, modificalo como te comento y te debería
>   de funcionar

**EJEMPLOS**

**//Correcto**

```
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@index');
```

**//incorrecto**

```
Route::get('/about', 'Home.php@index');
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funcionó, cree nuevamente el controlador y lo llamé siguiendo las indicaciones.Muchas gracias

Comment: Por supuesto indicame por favor, como hacerlo

Answer (score 3):

El error está en como defines la ruta, y tal vez como estás definiendo el namespace, pues normalmente debes incluir el nombre del controlador y su método, separados por una @:

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@base');
```

Lo otro que veo de particular en tu namespace, es que no debería incluirse el nombre del archivo del controlador (o de la clase), además es una buena práctica que el archivo y el nombre de la clase incluyan la palabra 'controller':

app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function base()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que el controlador (Controller) del cual deseas extender está ubicado en el namespace App\Http\Controllers.

Por último, en este caso en particular podrías obviar el método del controlador, pues simplemente quieres mostrar una vista, y podrías hacerlo directamente desde la definición de la ruta, usando `Route::view()`:

```
Route::view('/', 'index');
```

Más información en la documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#view-routes

Answer (score 0):

Como tu controlador se llama solo `Home` 
podrias intentar esto:

```
Route::get('/','Home@base');
```

aunque lo correcto es que el nombre del controlador sea `HomeController` para poder llamarlo.
Ejecuta con tu proyecto: `php artisan make:controller HomeController`para crear un nuevo controlador, ahi copias tu función `base`
y en tus rutas lo llamas de la manera correcta

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@base');
```

Comment: perfecto funcionó, gracias